# Restoring the 1-to-1 correspondence between elements in two lists, where one list is used as a guide to prune elements from the other

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

when we wish to use one list to select items from another using something like `Pick`, writing the following code, for example, causes us to lose the 1-to-1 correspondence between items in the two lists:

```
dataArray = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"};
testArray = {0.223,0.3,1.2,0.44,4,0.24449,1.01};
dataArray = Pick[dataArray, #>= 1 &/@ testArray];

output = {"C", "E", "G"}
```

Without having to make a copy of anything, how do we safely prune items from, here `testArray`, to restore the previous 1-to-1 correspondence between elements in `testArray` and elements in `dataArray`?  For example, if `B` in `dataArray` corresponds to `0.3` in `testArray` (based on its index), it should again do so after the `Pick` pruning step.

Comment: I'm not sure what is you goal at the end but maybe you can just work on pairs? `Select[Transpose[{dataArray, testArray}], #[[2]] > 1 &]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are surely many ways to approach this problem.  Which is best likely (again) depends on your data.  I will illustrate three variants.

### Paired data (a la decorate-and-sort)

We can do as Kuba did and merge the two lists into one to keep the elements together:

```
Select[{dataArray, testArray}\[Transpose], #[[2]] >= 1 &]
```

> ```
> {{"C", 1.2}, {"E", 4}, {"G", 1.01}}
> ```

You can finish with a second [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html) to separate the data into two lists.

### Reused mask

A typically faster method is to simply construct the mask once and then reuse it in `Pick` as needed:

```
mask = UnitStep[testArray - 1];

Pick[#, mask, 1] & /@ {dataArray, testArray}
```

> ```
> {{"C", "E", "G"}, {1.2, 4, 1.01}}
> ```

Note that I converted your test to a vectorized numeric form for better performance.

### Index-based filtering

Perhaps the top performing method for filter reapplication (especially in version 7 before `Pick` was better optimized) is to create a list of positions you wish to keep, then extract them using [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) or [`Extract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Extract.html).  Faster than [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Position.html), when applicable, is [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html), using the undocumented Properties method:

```
fastpos = SparseArray[#]["AdjacencyLists"] &;

idx = fastpos @ UnitStep[testArray - 1]
```

> ```
> {3, 5, 7}
> ```

```
#[[idx]] & /@ {dataArray, testArray}
```

> ```
> {{"C", "E", "G"}, {1.2, 4, 1.01}}
> ```

You can also process multiple lists at once with the help of [`All`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/All.html), like this:

```
{dataArray, testArray}[[All, idx]]
```

> ```
> {{"C", "E", "G"}, {1.2, 4, 1.01}}
> ```